# Calling the Constructor with Scanner

Tags: java

How do you call the constructor that is in another separate class in your main class with Scanner.

Suppose we have

```
public Person(String personFirstname, String personLastName, String personAddress, String personUsername)
{
    firstName = personFirstName;
    lastName = personLastName;
    address = personAddress;
    username = personUsername;
}
```

The suppose we have

```
public class PersonExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person dave = new Person();
    }
}
```

When we want the individual to fill in their own info regarding their name, last name, etc. how can we use the Scanner to have them fill in that info?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read that data in using the `Scanner`

e.g.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Your name?");
String name = scanner.nextLine();

// ... repeat for all fields ...

Person person = new Person(/*all the fields you just read*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some method that knows about both `Person` and `Scanner`, and it'll have your logic that reads the appropriate values and sets the fields. My recommendation is to have a `static` method on `Person` like this:

```
public class Person {
    public static Person createFromScanner(final Scanner scanner) {
        String firstName = scanner.next();
        // ...
        return new Person(firstName, lastName, address, username);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from somewhere else (like `main`) like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Person dave = Person.createFromScanner(scan);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
Person p = new Person(c.nextLine(), c.nextLine(), c.nextLine(), c.nextLine());
```

But this is not a good practice. It is better you validate user inputs first and then create an instance using those values